# Share Google Doc using a Google Script to set an array of emails (in Google Sheets) as editors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I basically am imagining commands that would change the sharing status of sheets it was allowed to edit. For example, I have a master document for a company (a "Roster" for keeping track of where employees are working and which other employees they are working with in that area) and other "Area Sheets" the employees use to keep track of progress. People move around quarterly, so I want to be able to update my Roster and then let the programming update the sharing status of their sheets instead of clicking on every sheet and copy-pasting emails.

As far as I know there is no current possible way to use google products to achieve this. Are there any other ways, barring a New Feature developed by Google?

Comment: As a part of asking a good question, you should have done research. This research should have consulted the Apps Script documentation. There is a simple method that adds editors to a given spreadsheet. There is a corresponding method that removes editors. There is a method to read  values - both all and specific - from a given spreadsheet. So this is entirely possible.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think I fully understand your requirements, so I'll start be rephrasing what I do understand.

1. For every employee, generate a list of who they're working with that quarter.
2. For a certain set of files owned by the employee, make those files editable to the employee's current co-workers.

For point 1, you already have the list built out in Google Sheets, so you can read the contents into arrays for processing. You can use [Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) for this. Example:

```
var roster = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //assuming the script is running within the Roster spreadsheet
var employeesSheet = roster.getSheetByName("Employees"); //assuming sheet name is "Employees"
var employeeEmails = employeesSheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues(); //assuming the emails are in column B with the first row as header

//In this next line I'm going to make a very big simplification.
//I will assume that the coworkers emails are listed as "coworker1@company.com;coworker2@company.com" in the cell.
//This is likely not the case, but you may already have this formatted in a way that works.
//If not, you can merge these values in Google Apps Script, but I'll consider that outside the scope of this question.
var coworkerEmails = employeesSheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues();
```

For point 2, I assume you already have a way of determining which files need to have their access permissions modified and that you have permission to make those modifications. You'll need to use the [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) for this part. In my example, I will assume that all relevant files are saved in a folder specific to each employee and that the folder ID is saved in column D.

```
var folderIds = employeesSheet.getRange("D2:D").getValues();
for (var i=0; i<employeeEmails.length; i++) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIds[i][0]);
  //At this point, you could give direct access to the entire folder,
  //or just to the files within the folder, as I will do.
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.addEditors(coworkerEmails[i][0].split(";"));
  }
}
```

Please note that in the above:

- This is untested code and meant only to demonstrate how to achieve what I *think* you're looking for.
- No access permissions are being revoked. This would be quite trivial to add, though.
- The `folder.getFiles()` command *only* gets files that are children of the folder. So, if the folder has child folders, you'll need to traverse through those as well.
- You may want to create a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addMenu(String,Object)) in your Roster spreadsheet to run this script

In the end, including the custom menu, your code could like:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Reset Permissions", functionName: "resetPermissions"});
  ss.addMenu("Roster Actions", menuEntries);
}

function resetPermissions() {
  var roster = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var employeesSheet = roster.getSheetByName("Employees");
  var employeeEmails = employeesSheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  var coworkerEmails = employeesSheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues(); 
  var folderIds = employeesSheet.getRange("D2:D").getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<employeeEmails.length; i++) {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIds[i][0]);
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      file.addEditors(coworkerEmails[i][0].split(";"));
    }
  }
}
```

For reference, this is how I assumed the example "Employees" sheet in the "Roster" spreadsheet to look:[image]